# Can Robocopy sync Files in a Directory between two pcs, Modifications of files on both pcs, but want to keep newest modifications/files synced

Tags: windows-10, command-line, sync, robocopy

So I am trying to keep a Minecraft Game Save Folder that is located in both PC A and PC B in sync. PC A and PC B will both access/modify the contents of the files in this folder periodically. I would like for Robocopy to be able to to check the contents of both directories and copy the most recently modified+new files to the PC that has older/fewer versions of the files. I have been experimenting with Robocopy and it seems like it may be able to. I have successfully been able to clone the contents from one to the other via the /MIR switch. I understand that this switch also acts as a purge, so if there are other files then they get deleted. I don't want that. I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022584/two-way-folder-sync-with-robocopy) and was able to extrapolate that the /E, /Z, /XO and /XX switches would be helpful/possibly be what I want/need to do what I am trying to do. Here is my code, it's in a batch file and for now I will run it manually, eventually, I will automate it:

```
@echo OFF
echo Syncing Between Alienware and HP Envy

robocopy "%LocalAppdata%\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds" "\\Gamer-pc\c\Users\UsernameHere\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds" /E /Z /XO /XX /MT:128

pause
```

I am not sure if I would need more code to get it to check both directories and sync whichever has the older/newer files.

Would it be the above code plus the reverse? Example below

```
@echo OFF
echo Syncing Between Alienware and HP Envy

robocopy  "%LocalAppdata%\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds" "\\Gamer-pc\c\Users\UsernameHere\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds" /E /Z /XO /XX /MT:128

echo Syncing Between HP Envy and Alienware

robocopy 

"\\Gamer-pc\c\Users\UsernameHere\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds"  "%LocalAppdata%\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\minecraftWorlds"  /E /Z /XO /XX /MT:128
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly you have to do the process in both directions, I recommend sharing the folders if they aren't already.

```
@echo off
robocopy "\\PC1\MinecraftShare" "\\PC2\MinecraftShare" /e /xo /z
robocopy "\\PC2\MinecraftShare" "\\PC1\MinecraftShare" /e /xo /z
```